# Google c2dm push notification clarification

Tags: android-c2dm

Receive push notification for some of the mobile.
when i connected through sim card of the mobile then it not responding properly for the
push notification from the Google c2dm.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,

c2dm works best when your mobile is using its own data network(eg. 3g).

But, some times when I'm connected through wifi, i'm getting some delay. I hope its because of some firewall which blocks my messages.

In my case, 3g works fluently for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what @Aki143S said. Seems that on 3G is more reliable.